# Save location for pinned items in office 2016

Tags: registry, ms-office

The company I work for decided to upgrade everyone from Win 8 with Office 2013 to Win 10 with Office 2016 and since we have an encryption client, doing a simple upgrade is out of the question.
Therefore we reinstall their devices completely. However users often complain that the pinned items they have in Office 2013 don't show up in Office 2016.
Which is why I'm writing a PS script to export the reg key.

I already found out that the pinned items are stored under the following reg key in Office 2013:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\User MRU\%user Identifier%\File MRU

Likewise for Excel and Powerpoint.
However I was unable to find the location where the pinned items are stored within Office 2016.
I checked the reg key for similar locations under the Office 2016 location, but the items that I pinned do not show up under any of those reg keys.

So my question is, where does Office 2016 save the pinned items for Word/Excel/Powerpoint?

Answer (score 0):

They're in the 16.0 folder instead of 15.0